# What is the best way to completely delete Apps or frameworks from Mac?

Tags: mac, macbook, uninstall

Most of the time dragging the app to the trash isn't enough to delete it, most apps will have a folder somewhere in the System root, and many files for caches, and many separated files everywhere in my system...

Each time I want to delete anything I have to make a google search for terminal commands I should run to completely delete and if this app isn't popular enough I will never be able to delete it...

Not only apps but also frameworks like npm, node, python, Django, composer, PHP, Laravel, Golang, PIP, etc... and so I find it very challenging to uninstall anything.

Any solution for this? like is there any command I can run in the terminal that will completely uninstall the wanted app and all of the files and directories it created in my system root? or an app that can do this (even if it's not free)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't get much simpler than [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) (freeware); but idk if it deals with frameworks too.

General rule is, if it needed an installer, it needs an uninstaller too. If it was drag & drop, it doesn't - though it will leave leftovers, prefs etc, which is where AppCleaner comes in.
Drag & drop any app you want to trash. Have a quick look at the list it presents, just in case it's found a shared resource [extremely rare] & you're done.

No affiliation.

Comment: It's better than the normal drag to trash at least, but... I tried it with Pycharm, it deleted some files, however, after uninstalling Pycharm I checked their website on how to delete it https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/uninstall.html#standalone and found out that AppCleaner didn't delete any of the directories in ~/Library, am I doing anything wrong?.And thank you so much for the recommendation, it's way better than the normal trash

Comment: I've no idea how it's meant to work with that type of install - it's designed for user apps.

Comment: Ok, thank you so much. This app deletes user apps perfectly 

Answer (score 0):

As Tetsujin mentioned, AppCleaner is a great free app to do this. I have found that the paid version of CleanMyMac X does a slightly better job and finds more frameworks to delete. You could also try to manually find the files to delete if there are still problems.